# Execute ECS task from Dagster

Tags: python, amazon-ecs, dagster

I am relatively new to Dagster. I am trying to execute an ECS task from dagster using this standalone python file as a job:

```
from dagster import job, op

@op()
def my_op(context):
  context.log.info('running')

@job(
  tags={
    "ecs/task_definition": "arn_task_definition",
    "ecs/container_name": "container_name"
  }
)
def my_job():
  my_op()
```

Command to execute:

```
dagster dev -f hello_dag.py
```

In the logs, I am able to get "running". But, I couldn't find any logs related to ECS. I also checked ECS console, but there are no task triggered. Can someone please help with executing the ECS task? Thanks